# Is there possible group chat using parse in android?

Tags: android, parse-platform, chat

I am developing a chat application in android using parse.I following this link.
https://parse.com/docs/android_guide

Now I am able to one to one chat.But is there possible group chat using parse.

If anyone have idea please reply.

Answer (score 0):

Group chat can be achieved by either setting the ACL of each member of the group read/write permission to the chat PFObject. Or if you just want everyone to be able to read and write set public read access.